# How to link the entire table cell via route

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-9

I have a table where these two columns are present. What I want to do is not only click on the button to be redirected to a page, but also on the entire cell, i.e. around the button, without necessarily clicking on it.

Can you kindly help me?

[image]

**td with href**

`<td class="centered"><a class="btn btn-secondary btn-size fw-bold" href="{{route('beer.index' , ['id' => $wineshop->id])}}" class="link-primary">{{ $wineshop->beers_count }}</a></td>`

Table:

```
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Beer</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($wineshops as $wineshop)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $wineshop->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $wineshop->name }}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-warning btn-size fw-bold" href="{{route('beer.index' , ['id' => $wineshop->id])}}" class="link-primary">{{ $wineshop->beers_count }}</a></td>

           </tr>
```

Comment: Can you please show the full table format ?

Comment: @PrashantPrajapati Done, I put the table as required

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing this is using JavaScript [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)

```
<td onclick="window.location='{{route('beer.index' , ['id' => $wineshop->id])}}'" style="cursor: pointer;"><a class="btn btn-warning btn-size fw-bold" href="{{route('beer.index' , ['id' => $wineshop->id])}}" class="link-primary">{{ $wineshop->beers_count }}</a></td>
```